# Extracting text with the inner and outer-most boundary with Perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

Given this two text as example

```
my $line = "[cytokine]<ADJVNT-PROP-0> signaling, which have not [to]<PREP> date been shown [to]<PREP> be [[regulat]<EXP-V-0>ed]<EXP-PP-V-0>";
my $line2 = "[Human [papillomavirus]<VACC-PROP-0>]<VACC-PROP-0> genotype [31]<NUM> does not [express]<EXP-V-0> detectable [microRNA]<MIR-0> levels [during]<PREP> latent or productive virus replication.";
```

What I want to do to extract all the string that are bounded by `<VAC` or `<ADJ` and `<EXP`
On the left side when there are multiple match extract the string from innermost 
onwards to the end to the right until the further most.

For example the above result I want to have a single regex that returns these:

```
Output1: signaling, which have not [to]<PREP> date been shown [to]<PREP> be [[regulat]<EXP-V-0>ed]
Output2: genotype [31]<NUM> does not [express]
```

Why this code doesn't work:

```
my @lines = ("[cytokine]<ADJVNT-PROP-0> signaling, which have not [to]<PREP> date been shown [to]<PREP> be [[regulat]<EXP-V-0>ed]<EXP-PP-V-0>",
"[Human [papillomavirus]<VACC-PROP-0>]<VACC-PROP-0> genotype [31]<NUM> does not [express]<EXP-V-0> detectable [microRNA]<MIR-0> levels [during]<PREP> latent or productive virus replication.");


my $count = 0;
foreach $line (@lines) {
    $count++;
    my ($sel) = $line =~ /<VAC|<ADJ.*>(.*)<EXP.*>/;
    print "Output $count: $sel\n";

}
```

Executable here: https://eval.in/50772

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: For the desired results, do you need the `<EXP` part as well? Your first line has it, while you second doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First your OR operator has the wrong scope:

```
/<VAC|<ADJ.*>(.*)<EXP.*>/
```

This will match either `<VAC` or `<ADJ.*>(.*)<EXP.*>`. Wrap the needed part around non-capture groups:

```
/<(?:VAC|ADJ).*>(.*)<EXP.*>/
```

Then, I think it's safer to use some negated class here, and by that, I mean `[^>]+` instead of `.*`:

```
/<(?:VAC|ADJ)[^>]+>(.*)<EXP[^>]+>/
```

Lastly, you don't seem to want any `<VAC` or `<ADJ` in the captures. So I added a negative lookahead (and made the `(.*)` lazy) in the `(.*)` part:

```
/<(?:VAC|ADJ)[^>]+>((?:(?!<VAC|ADJ).)*?)<EXP[^>]+>/
```

[eval.in updated](https://eval.in/50775)

If you want to get the `<EXP` part in (your first example), extend the capturing group:

```
/<(?:VAC|ADJ)[^>]+>((?:(?!<VAC|ADJ).)*?<EXP[^>]+>)/
```

[eval.in for this part](https://eval.in/50776).

Answer (score 2):

Several problems:

1. `|` means "or", but you did not use any kind of parentheses, so it is `<VAC` or the rest. You in fact want `<VAC` or `ADJ`, then the rest.
2. `.*` is greedy. It matches as much as it can. If you want it to match less, use `.*?`.
3. The regex tries to match as soon as possible. If you want it to match later, prepend a greedy `.*`.

This should work:

```
/.*<(?:VAC|ADJ).*?>(.*)<EXP.*>/
```